# How to use SQL between query together use other conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wanted to use `like` query together with `between query`...how can i combine them together?
this is how I tried to do so?

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$lastWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days"));
$selected_value = $search_value = $_POST["category"]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM work WHERE category like '%$selected_value%' AND date_added BETWEEN '" . $lastWeek . "' AND  '" . $today . "'";
```

what I wanted is to select all data lists from work `column` where category is `some value` and the date is inserted in the last 7 days... how can I fix this error?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, learn to use parameters, rather than munging query strings with values.

Comment: *"how can I fix this error?"* - What error is that?

Comment: When I use the above query I get nothing in return

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 2):

Let the database do the date work:

```
SELECT *
FROM work
WHERE category like CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND
     date_added >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND
     date_added <= CURDATE() ;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder used to pass in a value.

Comment: there is a missing `)` where should it be closed?

Answer (score -2):

Little improvement of Gordon Linoff answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM work
WHERE category like CONCAT('%', $selected_value, '%') AND
     date_added >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND
     date_added <= CURDATE();
```

Comment: This won't even work (missing single quotes) and just introduces a security hole. The missing parenthesis is already fixed in Gordons answer.